# Keep last n business days records from today date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, logic

How can we keep last n business days records from today date in this table:

```
Suppose n = 7
```

**Sample Data:**

**Table1:**

```
Date
----------
2021-11-29
2021-11-30
2021-12-01
2021-12-02
2021-12-03
2021-12-04
2021-12-05
2021-12-06
2021-12-07
2021-12-08
2021-12-09
2021-12-10
2021-12-11
2021-12-12
2021-12-13
```

Based on this table data we want output like below. It should delete all the rows before the 03-Dec or data for last 7 business days.

```
Date
-------
2021-12-03
2021-12-06
2021-12-07
2021-12-08
2021-12-09
2021-12-10
2021-12-13
```

**Note:** It's fine if we keep data for Saturday, Sunday in between business days.

I tried this query

```
DECLARE @n INT = 7

SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE  [date] < Dateadd(day, -((@n + (@n / 5) * 2)), Getdate())
```

but Saturday, Sunday logic doesn't fit here with my logic. Please suggest better approach.

Comment: Using arithmetic to determine business days is usually the wrong approach.  Instead create a calendar table with a column that stores whether a day is a business day.

Comment: But I don't want to handle holidays here, just want to handle Saturday, Sunday logic.

Comment: It's _still_ easier to use a calendar table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the 7th working day from today as

```
  select top(1) cast(dateadd(d, -n + 1, getdate()) as date) d
  from (
    select  n
       , sum (case when datename(dw, dateadd(d, -n + 1, getdate())) not in ('Sunday',  'Saturday') then 1 end) over(order by n) wdn
    from (
       values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)
    )t0(n)
  ) t
  where wdn = 7
  order by n;
```

Generally using on-the-fly tally for a @n -th day

```
declare @n int = 24;

with t0(n) as (
  select n 
  from (
    values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
  ) t(n)
), tally as (
     select top(@n + (@n/5 +1)*2) row_number() over(order by t1.n)  n
     from t0 t1, t0 t2, t0 t3
)
select top(1) cast(dateadd(d, -n + 1, getdate()) as date) d
from (
  select  n
     , sum (case when datename(dw, dateadd(d, -n + 1, getdate())) not in ('Sunday',  'Saturday') then 1 end) over(order by n) wdn
  from  tally
) t
where wdn = @n
order by n;
```

Comment: What about if  n = 10, your query returns Null.

Comment: For 10 working  days the `t0` tally must have 16 rows. Because max 6 days off could be found.

Comment: How can be set dynamic rows in t0, because n=.. can be any number.

Comment: @AnkitJain, see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update 

Answer (score 2):

You can use CTE to mark target dates and then delete all the others from the table as follows:

```
; With CTE As (
Select [Date], Row_number() Over (Order by [Date] Desc) As Num
From tbl 
Where DATEPART(weekday, [Date]) Not In (6,7)
)
Delete From tbl
Where [Date] Not In (Select [Date] From CTE Where Num<=7)
```

If the number of business days in the table may be less than 7 and you need to bring the total number of days to 7 by adding days off, try this:

```
Declare @n Int = 7

; With CTE As (
Select [Date], IIF(DATEPART(weekday, [Date]) In (6,7), 0, 1) As IsBusinessDay  
From tbl
)
Delete From tbl
Where [Date] Not In (Select Top(@n) [Date] From CTE Order By IsBusinessDay Desc, [Date] Desc)
```

Comment: It would work except one case, if we need to keep data for Saturday and Sunday, those are in between Today - n (Number of business days). We want to delete all the data before Today - n (Number of business days). e.g. In current case, your query will delete data for 4th and 5th Dec as well. But if we want to keep that data then?

Comment: This will delete starting from last date in the tbl. OP asks for  "starting from today date"

Comment: Yes, this CTE will delete based on the table data, but we want to delete from Today date to.... It may be possible we don't have last few days data in the table.

Comment: @Ankit Jain I've added a new solution if I understood the described case correctly.

Comment: It didn't work for me, the case is, suppose we below data in the table:

Date
----------
2021-11-29
2021-12-01
2021-12-02
2021-12-03
2021-12-05
2021-12-08
2021-12-09

and n=3 and current date is 13-Dec-2021. Then we should keep data for 13-Dec (Monday), 10-Dec (Friday), 9-Dec (Thursday) only, rest of the data should delete from table. As in above case we need to keep only 9-Dec data as we don't have 13, and 10 dec data.

Comment: @Anton Gig: Thanks for the answer 

Comment: There is no need for a self-join or subquery, you can delete directly from the CTE

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for response. For this particular case, I used a subquery, as I need to get target dates using Top(@n).

Answer (score -1):

If there is only one date for each day, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT TOP 7 [Date] FROM Table1 
WHERE 
  [Date] < GETDATE() AND DATENAME(weekday, [DATE]) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
ORDER BY
  [DATE] DESC
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be work with the question asked. Please update your answer according to use case asked in the question. Btw Thanks for the answer 